# SpringBoot ComponentScan issue with multi-module project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a myapp parent pom type maven project with myapp-core and myapp-web modules. myapp-core module is added as dependency to myapp-web.

All the classes in myapp-core module reside in root package **com.myapp.core** and all classes in myapp-web module reside in root package **com.myapp.web**

The main Application.java is also in com.myapp.web package. As my core module root package is different I am including common base package **"com.myapp"** for ComponentScan as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.myapp")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }   
}
```

Now the surprising thing is if I run this app using **Run As -> Spring Boot App** it is working fine. But if I run it as **Run As -> Java Application** it is failing with error saying it can't found beans defined in myapp-core module.

If I move my `Application.java` to `com.myapp` package it is working fine.
It should work even if i run it as Java Application also, right?

Comment: Only if the classpath is correct, when you run it as Java application. So check your run configuration, if all dependencies are included.

Comment: I have the same pom dependencies in both situations and same Application.java I am running.

Comment: I'm not talking about the POM, i'm talking about the classpath, which the IDE is constructing for your run configuration. Since you don't specify the IDE, i can't help you more.

Comment: I can say that it is not because of classpath. Because if I simply move the Application.java to com.myapp package it is working fine. So i guess it has to do something with @ComponentScan.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After enabling debug log level for spring and going through extensive logs I found that scanning for various components like JPA Repositories, JPA Entities etc are depending on the Application.java's package name.

If the JPA Repositories or Entities are not in sub packages of `Application.java`'s package then we need to specify them explicitly as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.sivalabs.jcart")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.sivalabs.jcart")
@EntityScan(basePackages="com.sivalabs.jcart")
public class Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

With the above additional `@EnableJpaRepositories`, `@EntityScan` I am able to run it using **Run As -> Java Application**.

But still not sure how it is working fine when **Run As -> Spring Boot App**!!

Anyway I think it is better to move my `Application.java` to `com.myapp` package rather than fighting with SpringBoot!

Comment: the spring boot documentation advises to put the main class in the root directory, so move it to com.myapp. This was you don't need to worry if the paths are correct, because everything from root will be scanned.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Only adding the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation can solve the issue. I tried to define basePackages in @SpringBootApplication, to no avail.
I think the package of the Application class is fed to the scanning process of JpaRepositories, but other packages defined in @SpringBootApplication are ignored.
It looks like a bug/improvement of Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Redis repositories that was fixed in a similar way:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({RedisProperties.class})
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableRedisRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.another"})
public class RedisConfig {

    private final RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template = new RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }
}
```